# Google Chrome is failing in loading require.js files in time

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, requirejs, chrome-browser

On Magento 2 (ver 2.2.5), with Google Chrome (ver 72.0) I'm getting a wired error I wasn't getting withe previous Google Chrome version (ver 71).
When I visit a product page, I get more then one `Uncaught TypeError:` from the Console, which makes several JS actions failing.

For instance, the first I got is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RFC_2822' of undefined
```

The error is referring to this bit of code:

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){

//<![CDATA[
    $.extend(true, $, {
        calendarConfig: {
            dayNames: ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],
            monthNames: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
            infoTitle: "About the calendar",
            firstDay: 0,
            closeText: "Close",
            currentText: "Go Today",
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next",
            weekHeader: "WK",
            timeText: "Time",
            hourText: "Hour",
            minuteText: "Minute",
            dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822, // << Here what's triggering the error
            showOn: "button",
            showAnim: "",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            buttonImageOnly: null,
            buttonImage: null,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showWeek: true,
            timeFormat: '',
            showTime: false,
            showHour: false,
            showMinute: false
        }
    });

    enUS = {"m":{"wide":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"abbr":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}}; // en_US locale reference
//]]>

});
</script>
```

The problem here is that that code comes from the Magento core, so I'm not very keen on changing it.
I found that code in the following two files:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/calendar.phtml
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml
```

Now, the code (`<script>....</script>`) is in the product page, while the missing object comes from the library datepicker.js which is loaded by require.js as I can see from the browser network inspector, but I guess too late to be used by that block of code.
The require.js is in the `<header>` block

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://website.com/static/frontend/vendor/my-module-theme/en_GB/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Is anyone experiencing the same thing?
Which one is the best way to fix it?

Comment: I have this issue too, I noticed in the network monitor everything loads and then suddenly it stops for a couple of seconds, is this what you're seeing too?